# How to push to a repo using SSH URLs

Tags: git, github

I have a GitHub Action I am trying to build that makes some changes to a file, and then tries to auto-commit the changes to the repo. However, I need to use an ssh URL to push.

[In the github docs](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/which-remote-url-should-i-use), it says I can use ssh URLs to push, but doesn't provide syntax as to how to do it.

Does anyone know how to do it?

One key thing to note is that I cannot generate an ssh key on this computer since it's running as a github action and I don't have access to the computer.

Right now I have `git push origin HEAD:master` but that will use HTTPs rather than SSH.

Comment: What's the problem with using HTTPS?

Comment: It's on a remote server and running automatically so I cant manually type in my username and passsowrd

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#_git_urls_a_id_urls_a

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+ssh+url+syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is part of the yaml file I wrote that will run a file, and then commit an updated lof file to the repo:

```
- name: Run a one-line script
      run: python ./.github/workflows/todo_List.py
    - name: switching from HTTPS to SSH
      run: git remote set-url origin ${{ secrets.ssh }}
    - name: check for changes
      run: git status
    - name: stage changed files
      run: git add .
    - name: commit changed files
      run: git commit -m "Auto updating TODO.txt"
    - name: fetch from master
      run: git fetch origin master
    - name: push code to master
      run: git push origin HEAD:master
```

where `${{ secrets.ssh }}` is `"https://__INSERT_DEPLOY_KEY_FROM_GITHUB__@github.com/user_or_org/repo.git"`

Answer (score 5):

You can find the `ssh-url` to a repo in their github page.
I attached a photo where you can find the ssh-url.

Then you can just add the ssh url running the following command:

```sh
git remote set-url origin <new.git.ssh.url>
```

Hope it solves your problem.

[image: SSH url]

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add another remote for example like this

```
git remote add origin_ssh <ssh-url>
```

and then push to the new remote

```
git push origin_ssh
```

Note origin is the default remote, but you can also rename it and then use the ssh-url as default